# How to make this list reversing algo more efficient python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to reverse various lists, I feel my code is some what elegant, can any one make it more beautiful ?

```
board = [1,2,3,5]
board = [config[len(config)-1-i] for i,house in enumerate(config)]
print board

#expected output [5,3,2,1]
```

Comment: Ok so I just realized there's reverse() function. Still without using that, how can we reverse a list with basic operators

Comment: Look at slice syntax `list[start:end:step]` you can simply do `list[::-1]`

Comment: Do you want more beautiful or more efficient? Question name asks A, question content asks B

Comment: Why does it need reversing?

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
In [2]: board[::-1]
Out[2]: [5, 3, 2, 1]
```

See here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice

And for a generator, see here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
In[45]: board = [1,2,3,5]

In[46]: board.reverse()

In[47]: board
Out[47]: [5, 3, 2, 1]
```